# how to convert the JSON object into form data and send it as Data to web api fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, asp.net-web-api

I am having a json object in the client side and i want to receive that in the Web api controller like **controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["Name"]** How to send that Json from web API.

The Data expected as **"name=abc&type=xyz"** for the fetch api. How to convert the JSON  object

```js
 {
name: abc,
type:xyz
}
```

below code is not working

```js
{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            body: JSON.stringify({
            name:abc,
            type:xyz
            })
          };
```

Replacing body and header as below works fine

```js
 body: "name=abc&type=xyz"
 headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
       }
```

How to convert the Json object as above and what is the reason for that .?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ASP.NET but I believe there's a way out there you can configure your data type to JSON instead of form-urlencoded. Or you need to customize how server parsing data.

If you can not change to application/json. You can use [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) package to stringify your JSON obj into urlenconded format.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your .NET code ?

Request Body doesn't take value like Params!

Body should take data from JSON.

You can use [FromBody] attribute!
or can create a DTO for this. DTO should take care of this automatically!